VSCODE RUBY 'Invalid argument @ realpath_rec' error and wont stop on any breakpoints
Both these problems are resolved (as shown) only posting to save someone else with either problem time
I had permission problems on the ruby directory while installing a gem, had seen this before and only sure way around was to remove and reinstall ruby.
I decided to update at same time, was running ruby 3.2.5 and vscode 1.85.1 and moved to ruby 3.3.5 and VSCode 1.93.1
When restarted my poject started getting the following error
31mDEBUGGER: ReaderThreadError: Invalid argument @ realpath_rec - C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw-ucrt/3.3.0/debug-1.9.1/d:
[0m[31mDEBUGGER: Disconnected.
[0m[31mDEBUGGER: wait for debugger connection...
[0m
After spending several hours trying to fix found it was actually caused by my launch.json file.
I also went back to ruby 3.2.5 and VSCode 1.85.1 thinking it may be causing problem.
  {
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [   
      {
      "type": "rdbg",
      "name": "MAIN",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "script": "${workspaceRoot}/main.rb"
      },
      {
          "type": "rdbg",
          "name": "Debug current file with rdbg",
          "request": "launch",
          "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
          "script": "${file}",
      } 
 ]
 }

Above is the failing file. After changing a few lines in this file without luck i copied in
another launch.json from another directory which fixed the problem.
Now after making one of my changes to this file, i must have forgot to save it prior to testing as in now works.   But above is as close to original file that i have.  Also I believe it only failed when selecting 'current file' rather than 'main' but no longer sure.
Now when went to debug a file I found that VSCode was not stopping on ANY breakpoints.
Eventually I found that whenever I created a GEMFILE (even an empty one) and it created the
GEMFILE.lck file the debugger would fail.
It worked fine with no GEMFILE.  After an hour of troubleshooting I went back to the updated ruby 3.3.5 and VSCode 1.93.1. and I no longer had the problem.
Did not pursue beyond this.
